# Hide UIButton without using "hidden" or "disabled"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to prevent the user do press a button, during an animation I run.
I don't want to hide the button, or to change it's image.
I can't use enabled = false, because I use this option to another situation, and it has different image.

I did try to cover the button with transparent Image, but it seems to not work, only real images can hide the button and prevent from the user to press on it.

The code that didn't work:

```
  skipBTN.enabled = FALSE;   //this one is not good for me
  skipBTN.hidden = TRUE;     //this one is also not good for me
```

This one didn't actually worked (The user still can press the button)

```
buttonsCover = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"empty"]];
buttonsCover.frame = button.frame;
[self.view addSubview:buttonsCover];
buttonsCover.hidden = YES;
```

and when it needed:

```
buttonsCover.hidden = NO;
```

I need another idea please :)

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to still press the button?  If yes, set the alpha to 0.  If no, why doesn't setting `enabled` or `hidden` properties work for you?  You need to explain in great detail why these do not work, because these are your options.

Comment: can you please try `skipBTN.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE`?

Comment: @nhgrif Setting the `alpha` to zero is the same (mostly) as hiding the button which the OP stated is not what is wanted.

Comment: @rmaddy That was embedded in an `if` ... following a question for clarity.  I don't know what he's trying to do... it doesn't make sense to me, and he hasn't fully explained why the ways he should be using won't work...

Comment: The question is quite clear. He wants to update a button so it can't be tapped but without changing its appearance.

Comment: @lootsch, great idea, works like a magic! you can add it as an answer, and I will approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `disable` the button without changing it's appearance, i recommend:

```
skipBTN.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE
```

See also: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled)

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few options but the simplest would be to use `disabled`. To solve the issue of the button appearing differently when it is disable, use the `UIButton setImage:forState:` (or other appropriate method) and specify a state of `UIControlStateDisabled`. By setting the same image you used for the `UIControlStateNormal` state, the button will look the same when disabled.

Comment: thanks, but the solution "Lootsch" suggested is the one I needed. Thanks anyway :)